# conditionally changing values in a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array (of variable size) of 1s and 2s that I check for 1s. Once I find the first 1 in the first row, I have to set it and each neighboring 1 to a 0 until all touching 1s become 0s and the 1s that are encased by 2s stay as 1s. Also, the program quits if there are no 1s in the first row.

My question is how to conditionally change each 1 to a 0 (I think a recursive method would be most efficient for this?) and what the condition would be to exit when the first row has no 1s in it.

language is java

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: java sorry forgot to put that in

Comment: Then add a java tag.

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear. If there is at least one '1' in the first row of the array, do you then carry on to the next row? Does the program quit if the row it is currently working on has no '1'? By "encasing" do you mean that 22122... would be left unchanged, but 221122 would be changed to 220022....? What course is this?

Comment: I'd like to see what you've tried thus far to accomplish this but a partial hint would be `arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] == 1 ? 0 : 2;` assuming there's only 1s and 2s.

Comment: can you post what you have done so far?